# Please could someone check and help me with my answer to part two of this exercise about vector fields along maps?

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I previously solved the following (first half of an) exercise:

Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $0 \in \mathbb R^2$ and let $f = (f_1, f_2) : U \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth map such that $f(0) = 0$. Furthermore let $\operatorname{ord}{(f_1)} = n $ be finite where $\operatorname{ord}{(f_1)} = \min \{n \in \mathbb N_{>0}\mid f_1^{(n)}(0) \neq 0\}$.

Show that there exists a vector field $v$ along $f$ and a neighbourhood of zero such that on the neighbourhood $v$ is not zero and the linear span of $f'(x)$ is contained in the linear span of $v$ on that neighbourhood.

For the vector field I defined $(v_1,v_2)$ where $v_1 (x) = f_1^{(n)} (x)$ and $v_2(x) = f_2' (x)$.

Now here is the second part of the exercise:

State necessary conditions for the existence of an immersion $\widetilde{f}: \operatorname{dom}{(f)} \to  \operatorname{Gr}{(1, T\mathbb R^2)}$  such that  $f = \pi \circ \widetilde{f} $ where $\pi: \operatorname{Gr}{(1, T\mathbb R^2)} \to \mathbb R^2$ is the canonical projection and $\operatorname{Gr}{(1, T\mathbb R^2)} = \bigsqcup_{x \in \mathbb R^2} \operatorname{Gr}{(1, T_x\mathbb R^2)}$.

Here is my answer:

Let $\widetilde{f} (x) = (f(x), v(x)))$. Then the Jacobian is given by

$$ J_{\widetilde{f}}  = \left(\begin{array}{c} f'(x) \\ v'(x)\end{array}\right)$$

This has rank one if and only if not both entries are zero. So $\widetilde{f}$ is an immersion on a neighbourhood of $0$ if and only if not both $f'(0)$ and $v'(0)$ are zero.

Unfortunately, this is a sufficient condition. But it's not clear how to improve it.

How to find the necessary condition for the existence of such an immersion?